# Null connection variable

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, database-connection, prepared-statement

I have a problem and I can't seem to find an answer to it. I have two classes called Harta.java and DBOperations.java. In Harta.java I am getting the coordinates from a database to display a marker when I start my application and in DBOperations I am connecting to the database.

I'll explain in depth, this is the method in my Harta.class

```
DBOperations operations = new DBOperations();

...

public void markers() {

        double latitude, longitude;

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String sql = "SELECT id, ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom) FROM modul";

        PreparedStatement prepst;
        try {
            prepst = operations.conexiune.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = prepst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                longitude = rs.getDouble("ST_X(geom)");
                latitude = rs.getDouble("ST_Y(geom)");

                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(
                        "Marker " + id));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Harta.class.getName(), "query failed to execute: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The NullPointerException occurs on this line:

```
prepst = operations.conexiune.prepareStatement(sql);
```

And apparently this operations.conexiune (DBOperations operations = new DBOperations) is null but I have no idea why. I have several methods in my DBOperations.java but I'll only show you two things. My connect() method that I call to open the connection to my database:

```
private String DB_URL = "...";
private String DB_USER = "...";
private String DB_PW = "...";
public Connection conexiune;

...

public Connection connect() {
        try {
            new Connect().execute();
            Log.d(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                    "Se incearca deschiderea conexiunii.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                    "Incercarea de a deschide conexiunea a esuat.");
        }
        return conexiune;
    }
```

And my Asynctask class I use to do my connection to the database. (PS: I am connecting (succesfully) to the database in my main activity's OnCreate method.)

```
class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Log.e(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                        "Database driver is working fine.");
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                Log.e(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                        "Database driver is broken: " + e1);
            }

            try {
                conexiune = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PW);
                Log.e(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                        "Succesfully connected to the database.");
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                Log.e(DBOperations.class.getName(),
                        "Database connection error: " + e2);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

As I stated earlier, the nullpointerexception points out to that line but I have no idea where the issue is so I hope you can help me out and point me out in the right direction.

Comment: you show your `public Connection connect()` code, but I can not see it being called anywhere.

Comment: If the call to `operations.conexiune.prepareStatement(sql)` is throwing the NPE, then either `operations` or `conexiune` is `null`. You should show us, where these variables (or fields) are declared _and_ initialized.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: You missed this line: (PS: I am connecting (succesfully) to the database in my main activity's OnCreate method.)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: DBOperations operations = new DBOperations(); as a 'global' variable in my Harta.java.
public Connection conexiune; in my DBOperations.java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your problem is that you are using an `AsyncTask` to create your DB connection and you are returning it in your `connect` method. Probably when you are doing `return conexiune;` your connection is not ready yet, asi it is being initalized in a different `Thread`.

One possible solution (there are plenty of them) could be to use `OnPostExecute` (from AsyncTask) to tell your class that you are ready to use your DB, and call any method you may want.

Another possibility is to use `new Connect().execute().get()` and return your connection there, but you will need to change your `AsyncTask` params and your UI will be freezed. So I think the first option is the best.

Use a `ProgressBar` to make the user wait while the connection is completing.

Finally another possibility (if your connection initialization does not last much), could just be putting your initialization code in your UI thread, but that is up to you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am in your debt, dear sir. I didn't figure out your first solution but your second solution did work. Thank you very much.